# What's a finite non-commutative ring?

Tags: ring-theory

Please give me some examples, this is an exam question of a 1st year math module.

Comment: Searching the web for _finite noncommutative ring_  finds this duplicate right here on stackexchange. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603881/example-of-a-finite-non-commutative-ring-without-a-unity

Comment: Oh I see... so nxn matrices with entries on $Z_k$ work?

Comment: Yes, one of the most obvious examples.

Comment: [Here are at least 8 examples](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=43&L=1)